# ExtJs: find a record, edit and post changes

Tags: extjs

i'm learning ExtJs.

I'm trying to accomplish a very easy task: find a record, edit data and post changes back.

I have defined the model class with the correct proxy.

Now my code is like this:

```
        const amodel=Ext.create('TestApp.model.theModel');

        amodel.set('id','001');

        amodel.load({
            success(rec) {
                // Ok, i have found the data

                rec.set('aField',rec.data.entity.aField+' MODIFIED'); // Update the field

                rec.save({ // Exception returned by the server cause data sent is not correct
                    success(rec) {
                      // The record has been updated      
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

What's my mistake ?

thanks

Roberto

Comment: Check in the network tab of the browser devtools the data sent to the server in the request. This has to match what the server expects.

Comment: Thanks Peter, actually your hint helped me to find the problem.

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. Changed my code as follow:

```
rec.set('aField',rec.data.entity.aField+' MODIFIED'); // Replaced by the following code

rec.data=rec.data.entity;
rec.set('aField',rec.get('aField')+' MODIFIED');
```

Comment: try to work with getter and setter. Example: `rec.setData(rec.get('entity'))`. This ensures events get fired and stores get updated. And classNames are should be uppercase, e.g. `'TestApp.model.TheModel'`

Comment: I cannot really understand why you would reset the data to the entity field of a record. Best to create a fiddle, so that you get the help you need.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions about getter and setter. I don't know what is a fiddle. I'll search for informations.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you asked for Fiddles. Here is the answer, plus some ideas about your code.

It might be a good idea to setup a fiddle:

```
fiddle.sencha.com
```

You need credentials from

```
https://forum.sencha.com/forum/register.php
```

Once you created your own fiddle, try to work with getter and setter.

@**Example**

```
rec.set(rec.get('entity')).
```

`rec.set` will fire an event from the model AND inform the store that you changed the record. Plus it will change `rec.data` accordingly.

**Hint**

ClassNames should be uppercase, e.g. 'TestApp.model.TheModel'

```
TestApp  Appname   (is PascalCase)
model    Directory (are lowercase)
TheModel Classname (FileNames and ClassNames are PascalCase)
```